# Having some trouble with DynamoDB.transactWriteItems

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm attempting to use DynamoDB transactions to update multiple tables simultaneously from a lambda using Node.js. I am receiving an error that 'transactWriteItems is not a function'. I'm following the documentation step for step and am not too sure what I'm doing incorrectly here. Here's what my function looks like:

```
'use-strict';
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
var dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-10-08'});

var date_created = (new Date).getTime().toString()

var media_id = event['media_id']

var params = {
    TransactItems: [
        {
            Put: {
                TableName: 'Table_Name',
                Item: {
                    "media_id": {S: event['media_id']},
                    "timestamp_date_liked": {N: date_created},
                    "liker_id": {S: event['liker_id']},
                    "type" : {N: event['type']},
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

var data = await dynamoDB.transactWriteItems(params).promise();
```

};

And the exact error I'm receiving is:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "dynamoDB.transactWriteItems is not a function",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:40:31)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is your apiVersion correct?  Documentation seems to suggest it should be `2012-08-10`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html

Comment: I've tried '2012-08-10' and '2012-10-08', but still receive the same error

Answer (score 2):

AWS has yet to update the lambda run time to the latest version of the aws-sdk, the version currently being used does not have dynamodb transactions.

Currently if you want to use transactions you will need to bundle in the current sdk version with your lambda or place it in a layer.

**Note:**
There are complications with using the aws-sdk in a layer. That is, the native version will still take priority. You can get around this by having a package installed in the layer that requires the aws-sdk using  a relative path ('../aws-sdk') and re exports it as a different package name, and use that package instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `transactWrite` instead of `transactWriteItems` if you are using [documentClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html).